# How can I include non-ascii characters like a proper apostrophe ’ in R help (.Rd files?)

Tags: r, rd

It’s common to want to use grammatical characters like the curly apostrophe in "It’s" in R help files.

Using a regular single quote `'` ) is not a great solution as `'` is used in roxygen line openings (`#'`) and to quote strings (which leads syntax-highlighting in text editors to break (not in the .Rd file).

**What doesn't work**

1. You can't just paste in unicode.

   - CRAN doesn't allow any non-ascii characters in packages for portability.
2. You can't use encoded unicode, e.g. \u2019

   - This renders as raw string.
3. You can't use &-escaped html codes.

   - `&rsquo;` renders as raw code in the help :-(

So: Are there solutions to including an apostrophe in Rd files?

Comment: I don't follow. Code is marked as `\code` in Rd files. What kind of syntax highlighting issues are you experiencing when using a single quote?

Comment: Also, it is possible to use utf8 encoding in your help files. However, CRAN does not like that very much due to portability issues. I don't even write my name with the correct non-ascii letters in my packages for that reason.

Comment: hmm. There's another question on SO somewhere about UTF-8 encoding in .Rd files but I can't find it at the moment ...